# Installing RVM on existing ruby1.8 installation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, debian

I have a big problem with my Debian server configuration. Someone before me has made a big mess with ruby installation and now i can't manage to get it all working. **What i'm trying to do now is to get back to environment, where ruby1.8 is installed and rails app is working correctly with apache+passenger**. If it would be working on RVM it would be perfect. Here is the story:

There was ruby 1.8 installed on a server. The person has removed it with `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.8` and then installed version 2.0.x manually using those commands:

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
curl --progress ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz | tar xz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then, he has removed all the dirs listed by `whereis ruby` with `rm` command.

And here i came - i want to install RVM on this server. The problem is, no matter what i do, i get a lot of errors from all sides. Steps i've done:

```
# Install RVM
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# install 1.8.7 version
rvm install 1.8.7

# use 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7

# Install gems
bundle install
```

First thing (and that's just a tip of iceberg) is that i'm not able to start apache2 in cause of the following error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax
>   error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load: Cannot
>   load
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
>   into server:
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Action
>   'configtest' failed.

Looks like there is even no `/usr/lib/ruby/` dir on my system right now.

The question is: is there any way to reset all ruby-releated libraries on debian to the original state (debian without ruby installed) and install working RVM on top of that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Verify if, Is ruby installed correct by `ruby -v`
2. Install phusion passenger

   `$ sudo gem install passenger`

`$ sudo passenger-install-apache2-module`
and then follow onscreen instructions